# How can I select a particular function to run based on a filename using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a function that will change the filename and move it to a specific computer. The function is duplicated for another computer, so I now have two specific functions for each filename. I can't seem to figure out how to get the script to choose the function I want it to use.  Here is what I've tried with no luck:

```
$files = dir -Path \\server\PPTV\*\*.* -Include atrium.*, clirel.* -Recurse {        
    (If ($file.FullName -eq "atrium.*" | Rename-Copy-Atrium), 
    (If ($file.FullName -eq "clirel.*" | Rename-Copy-Clirel)))
}
```

How can I get this to pipe to the function and run? Rename-Copy-Atrium for example is one of the function names.

Comment: How about maybe consolidating those functions instead? Also, the code you've posted is not valid powershell.

Comment: I think i have it set correctly, new to site, pardon me.

Comment: The functions will move a file after renaming it, and then reboot the computer the file was sent to. Can this even be done in one script?  I'm running it as a SQL job.  Would I need to just call the function from a separate file as it is needed?

Comment: It would definitely be easier to say if you could show us the functions

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for an `if()` statement in powershell is:

```
if([condition])
{
    [execute this code]
}
```

So you would want to do something like:

```
$files = dir -Path \\server\PPTV\*\*.* -Include atrium.*, clirel.* -Recurse 

foreach($file in $files)
{
    if($file.FullName -like "atrium.*") 
    {
        # I assume the function takes a fileinfo object as a parameter argument
        Rename-Copy-Atrium $file 
    }
    elseif($file.FullName -like "clirel.*")
    {
        Rename-Copy-Clirel $file 
    }
}
```

Comment: The above worked on only one of the functions.  I must be missing some character possibly so that the first function was skipped, but worked on the 2nd. I'll post my function after I review the whole thing.